# What is the easiest way to display an editable list(like a spreadsheet) in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, listview, spreadsheet, farpoint-spread

We have a requirement to display an editable list in a web page.

What would be the easiest way to do that? [Farpoint Spread](http://www.fpoint.com/products/spread/spread.aspx) was something I have used to achieve this earlier but it was quite slow when a large number of records were involved and it needed to be coded in VBScript. Besides it wasn't free.

I would be looking for a JavaScript solution and I can't afford to buy one. Also is there anything else you can think of other than a spread?

Answer (score 1):

I like [JQuery.Spreadsheet UI](http://os.arandomurl.com/jqueryspreadsheet/), try [this demo](http://os.arandomurl.com/jqueryspreadsheet/fullscreen.html), very nice...

Comment: I liked the looks of it..but is it reliable enough to be deployed in production??? It doesnt seem to hav any docs too??

Answer (score 0):

Also found at: http://code.google.com/p/completeui

Answer (score 0):

FarPoint has an ASP.Net solution: http://www.fpoint.com/netproducts/spreadweb/spread.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this guy: http://www.visop-dev.com/jquerysheet.html , this is on my list of things to try but I haven't got around to it! It's free but I think a donation would be nice.